# CoreData Abstract Entity and methods overridden

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, overriding

If I have two CoreData entities:

- An abstract entity A
- Entity B that has the A entity A as parent.

Suppose that I defined this method in the implementation of entity A.

```
- (NSString*) myHello;
```

.m

```
-(NSString*) myHello
{
  return @"Hi, I'm custom hello message...";
}
```

In the B entity implementation, Can I override this method:

.m

```
-(NSString*) myHello
{
  NSString *parentMessage = [super myHello];
  return  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@"], parentMessage, @" SubHello";
}
```

is possible this? Is good? in particular, how it works about the builders? 
if I wanted to redefine the constructors in my entity B can I use self = [super ....]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's perfectly fine. Another thing to do for that would be to create categories on each entity. That way, when you regenerate those entities from core data, you won't lose all your custom work.

A+CustomMessage.m:

```
-(NSString*) myHello
{
    return @"Hi, I'm custom hello message...";
}
```

B+CustomMessage.m:

```
-(NSString*) myHello
{
    NSString *parentMessage = [super myHello];
    return  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@"], parentMessage, @" SubHello";
}
```

Then wherever you would have normally imported "A.h" and "B.h" just import "A+CustomMessage.h" and "B+CustomMessage.h"